# Set title of parent navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UINavigationController` that pushes a `UIViewController` that has its own custom `UINavigationBar`. This means there are two `UINavigationBar`s showing at once. I can't seem to set the title of the navigation bar in the navigation controller.

I have tried using this code in the pushed view controller:

```
self.title = "A Title"
```

But it doesn't work. Any suggestions on how to set the title?

**UPDATE**

Ignore this I've been an idiot

Comment: can you share the code of your custom `UINavigationBar` ?

Comment: It's quite long, but basically I'm adding a subview to the custom navigation bar.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a navigation bar yourself, you can change title by doing.
navigationBar.topItem.title = "My Title"

---

You can try this in your view did load function.

self.navigationItem.title = "YourTitle"

Comment: Tried subclassing the navigation bar, used this code within it and just doesn't display. However the back button does display

Comment: The topItem gave me hint for my case. I had to use in my Swift3 case topViewController like this: self.navigationController?.topViewController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add,target: self, action: #selector(addTapped))

Answer (score 0):

You need to be doing something like this in the view controller where you need the title to be set.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
self.title = "some title"}
```

Comment: Like I said before, I've already tried this but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Wow I've just realised I've been a huge idiot. The text was showing all along, it was just the same colour as the navigation bar >.<